# How many different possible expressions?

Tags: combinatorics

Taking the integers $1, \dots, n$ we can form arithmetic expression using the four main operations +, -, * and /. If we also allow parentheses, how many different expressions can be made if you use each integer at most once? I am counting $1+2+3$ and $3+2+1$ as different expressions.  Not all the integers have be involved in a given arithmetic expression. I am assuming there are no redundant parentheses so $((1+2))$ is not allowed.

Examples could be:

$$ (5+3)\times 2 $$

or

$$3 + \frac{1}{(7 + (6-5)/(15 + 2/((10-8) + (11-9)/(20 \times 14+12+(17+16)/(13 \times 4)))))}$$

Comment: Is $(1+2)+3$ the same as $1+2+3$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe No it isn't.

Comment: Do you have a size limit? if not you have infinitely many expressions...

Comment: @JulesBesson Each integer is to be used at most once.I'll edit the question.

Comment: Otherwise I would define the function that maps an arithmetic expression to its value in $Q$ which seems to be a monoid morphism and work with it

Comment: Are expressions that cannot be evaluated allowed? For example, $1/(2+3-5)$.

Comment: @TonyMathew It might be too hard to exclude those so I will allow them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 4^{k-1} \frac{(k-1)! n!}{(n-k)!}$$

**Assumptions**:

1. Not using $-$ as a unary operator to flip sign. Otherwise, do $1; -1; -(-1))$ count as three different expressions? If so, this allows infinity.
2. Ignoring the concern whether the expression can be evaluated; e.g. $1/(2+3-5)$
3. Ignoring whether changing the order of evaluation actually changes the result; e.g. considering $(1+2)+3$ and $1+(2+3)$ as different

**Derivation**:

All possible expressions using exactly 3 integers, without parentheses and not using $-$ as a unary operator (to flip sign), can be written in the following form, where $\triangle, \square \in \{+,-,*,/\}; x,y,z \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.
$$x \triangle y \square z$$

Ignoring the concern whether the expression can be evaluated (e.g. $1/(2+3-5)$), and since we're allowing multiplicity of operations, the operands $\triangle, \square$ can be chosen from $\{+,-,*,/\}$ independent of each other and independent of the integers $\{x,y,z\} \subset \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. So the number of expressions is,
$$4\times4\times {}^n P_3 = 4^{3-1} \times {}^n P_3$$

So the total number of expressions using any number of integers from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, without parentheses and not using $-$ as a unary operator, is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 4^{k-1} \times {}^n P_k > \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 4^k \times 1^{n-k} \times {}^n C_k = \frac{5^n}{4}$$

The only effect of adding parentheses is changing the order in which the operands are evaluated in the expression, with the default being (PE)DMAS. Ignoring whether changing the order actually changes the result of evaluation (e.g. $(1+2)+3$ vs $1+(2+3)$), and ignoring redundant parentheses (that don't change the order of evaluation of binary operands), the total number of expressions becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)! \times 4^{k-1} \times {}^n P_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 4^{k-1} \frac{(k-1)! n!}{(n-k)!} $$

Not sure if the above sum collapses to a neat expression, like the binomial expansion. Also let me know if you have an example of an expression that I haven't accounted for.

Comment: Thank you for this.