# How to construct the smallest set of all algebraic expressions?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, field-theory, formal-grammar

I am a high school math teacher and I have a little side project that has been going on since some time: build a taxonomy of mathematical expressions.

Specifically, let's define a set of symbols $S$ and a set of $n$-ary operators $O$. A formula is defined as a tree with elements of $S$ at the leaves and elements of $O$ at the internal nodes.

For sake of concreteness, let's take a (not necessary commutative!) field $(F,+,\cdot)$ and consider the field $F(x,y,z)$ of rational expressions in three variables.

So $S=\{x,y,z\}\cup F$ and $O=\{+,\cdot,\text{opp},\text{inv}\}$, where $\forall \alpha \in S, \alpha+\text{opp}(\alpha) = \text{opp}(\alpha) + \alpha = 0_F$ and $\alpha\cdot\text{inv}(\alpha)= \text{inv}(\alpha)\cdot \alpha = 1_F$.

(I don't know if the requisite of $F$ being a field simplifies the task or not)

I now would like to enumerate all expressions of length $n$, where the length of the expression is defined as the number of nodes of its tree representation.
When I try to count all possible expressions, I want to count the really different ones, because there is the problem of counting duplicates.

I would like to say that the two expressions
\begin{equation}
x\cdot y\quad\quad x\cdot z
\end{equation}

are essentially the same because they are of the form "a variable times a possibily different variable". Still, I would like to keep the two expressions

\begin{equation}
x\cdot y\quad\quad y\cdot x
\end{equation}

separate, because "$\cdot$" may not be commutative.

What I am trying to do is construct an equivalence relation on the space of all the possible algebraic expressions which captures the sense of the expression disregarding the actual variable symbols that it uses. As another example, the expression
\begin{equation}
y+z
\end{equation}
should be a duplicate of $x+y$, the rationale behind this idea being that what I want to express is the concept of "a sum of two possibly different variables". So if I choose to count $x+y$ as the representation of this idea I could discard $y+z$. Note that I have still to keep $y+x$ and count it as different from $x+y$.

As another example, here are all the length $3$ expressions with only the variables $x,y,z$ and the "$+$" operator that I would count as valid:

\begin{equation}
x+x \qquad x+y \qquad y+x
\end{equation}

the following are not valid, because they express the same concept as the previous expressions:
\begin{equation}
x+z \qquad z+x \qquad y+y \qquad y+z \qquad z+y \qquad z+z
\end{equation}

So in this case to express every possible use of a single operator "+", it's obvious that we need at most $2$ variables, for instance $x$ and $y$; that is why every other expression with $z$ is essentially a duplicate.

My question is: could someone help me define the exact equivalence relation that I'm trying to express here? How to count every expression of length $n$ up to this equivalence relation?

EDIT: one could argue that also the expression $x+x$ is superfluous because the expression $x+y$ already has the possibility of expressing $x+x$. But $x+x$ is equivalent to $2\cdot x$ which is essentially different from $x+y$!

EDIT 2: I'll try to better explain myself since from the comments I understand that my thoughts are not really clear. Suppose I have only the product operation, "$\cdot$", and only one variable. I can express the idea of "multiplication" by writing $x\cdot x$. Of course, having only one variable, I can express only the idea of "multiplication of something by itself". Now, if we allow for a second variable, $y$, we can express the product of two things together, and if the product is non commutative, the order counts, so $x\cdot y$ should be considered different from $y\cdot x$. There are two essentially different ways to combine two things. We have now three possible expressions in total, each expressing a different concept in the context of how many variables we are considering. I argue that the expression "$y\cdot y$" is redundant, we don't need it because we already have an expression that means "a product of a thing by itself", which is $x\cdot x$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, given an expression, if we were to change the operands around one binary operator, we can get only three distinct expressions: same two operands, different operands, and different operands commutated

Comment: Well, that is the case of taking only variables into account, but since every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module I guess we have to consider all the numbers as operands...

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense to think of $xy$ and $xz$ as the same but $xy$ and $yx$ as different. After all isn't $yx$ also "a variable times a possibly different variable"? In order to express noncommutativity you must pay attention to the order of the inputs, which is why various formalizations of this idea don't bother quotienting by relabeling the inputs. Instead we can track the action of the symmetric group on the inputs, as in the theory of operads.

Comment: you might find interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad (operads, at least on the nose, are only about expressions where each variable is used at most once, but still)

Comment: See here [my answer][1] to a simpler version of your question. I don't confidently understand the logic for determining whether two different expressions should be counted the same or different, so I'm not sure how to adapt it.

  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724113/1102817

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The idea is that variables, if not needed, should not have an "identity" (in the sense of having a "soul" if that makes any sense :) ) - the expression "$xy$" declares two different variable identities, that of "$x$" and that of a (possibly) different "$y$". A third possibly different identity "$z$" is not needed to express the product of two "identities".

Comment: @QiaochuYuan to expand on my comment, I think of it this way: a "valid" expression declares that every variable in it has a possibly different identity, so "$xy$" introduces in the language the two variables "$x$" and "$y$". If we now add to the language the expression "$xz$", we are introducing a new entity "$z$" which is not needed to express the idea of a product, since we already had two entities beforehand. Does that make any sense?

Comment: But then $yx$ is also not needed to express the idea of a product, for the same reason. It seems to me that you aren't being consistent about whether the order matters. I have the same objection to regarding $x + y$ and $y + x$ as different.

Comment: How would you express in that language that the product may not be commutative other than  declaring that $xy\neq yx$?

Comment: I feel that in a language with 2 variables, $xx$, $xy$ and $yx$ are the only essentially different products and $yy$ is redundant because we have already the concept of a "product of a variable times itself", namely $xx$. The reason why $xy$ and $yx$ should count as different is because IF we have two variables the order matters; meanwhile IF we want to express a power, we only need one variable.

Comment: Again, I don't think you're being consistent about whether the order of the variables matters. Here is a straightforward equivalence relation: given two expressions $F(x_1, \dots x_n), G(y_1, \dots y_n)$, we could declare them equivalent if there is some bijection $x_i \to y_{\sigma(i)}$ between the variables in the first expression and the variables in the other expression such that substituting variables transforms one into the other. This equivalence relation identifies $xy$ and $xz$ just fine (we send $x \to x, y \to z$) but it also identifies $xy$ and $yx$ (we send $x \to y, y \to x$).

Comment: This is a straightforward natural equivalence relation, and it straightforwardly and naturally captures "expressing the same concept," since merely renaming the variables ought not change the concept being expressed. Noncommutativity can be expressed as the statement that the single expression $xy - yx$ is not identically zero. But there is no reason to regard $xy$ and $yx$ as expressing different concepts *unless* you are secretly thinking of the variables $x$ and $y$ as having a particular order, which you claim not to be (but which is standard practice here, actually).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'd be more than pleased if you would like to chat with me about this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148928/discussion-between-marco-trevi-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: If $xy$ is the same as $xz$, then presumably $xz$ is the same as $yz$, and $yz$ is the same as $yx$, so $xy$ is the same as $yx$ – oops!

Comment: why should $xz$ be the same as $yz$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson let me reframe the problem- if I have a one letter alphabet, {A}, I can make the only two-letter word "AA". But let's set a rule: if a word contains only one letter, we cannot tell what letter it is, so it's more like "$\star\star$". If we have a two letter alphabet, {A,B}, we can make the four 2-letter words "AA", "BB", "AB" and "BA" but with our rule "AA"="BB"="$\star\star$" so we end up with only 3 possible 2-letter words.

Comment: For context, solving this problem would save huge amount of space in building a database of expressions - things like "xyx", would mean the same thing as "yzy", "zyz", "xzx" and"zxz"... and still "yxy" would mean something different

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not with you. How can yzy be zyz, but xyx not be yxy?

Comment: I might be overcomplicating things, and might well be dwelling in an aberrant thought process, but I'd like, for optimization purposes, to think that IF we already have xyx and yxy, we have already realized these two specific combinations of variables so we don't need zyz or yzy or wuw for whatever matters. But I'm starting to think that my logic is not really useful